# Solubility of multiple solutes and limits of solubility during freezing

Tags: aqueous-solution, solubility, solutions, alcohols, phase

I'm interested in modeling the freezing of solutions of water and I'm not really sure what happens in water after the solubility of a given material is reached. I know that as ice crystals form they form into pure crystals of water so during freezing solute concentration of the liquid phase increases. I also know that the solubility of sugar is around 80g/100g and I know that the solubility of salt is about 36/100g (room temperature assumed, I realize solubility might change with tempature but I'm going to ignore that).

My understanding of these terms is such that if I add 81g of sugar to 100g of water, I should see about 1g of sugar participate out or never dissolve. Likewise I imagine that as I froze a solution of sugar and water, after enough of the water had frozen the sugar would start to precipitate out once the ratio of sugar to water had reached 80 to 100 (assuming temp didn't affect solubility). Please correct my understanding if this part is wrong.

What I don't think I know is what would happen if I started with a solution of sugar AND salt. What would the relative concentration of the liquid phase be (or equivalently, what would the ratio of the precipitates be?). How does adding in a miscible fluid like alcohol change this?

If it helps to give a more specific answer I'm primarily only interested in the following solutes:
ethanol, mono and disaccharides (e.g. sugars), glucose polymers, and salts such as sodium and potassium chloride.

Comment: If they are ideal solutions (which many are not), it is "easy". The less ideal, the harder it gets. Modeling ternary phase diagrams is hard.

Comment: Is there somewhere that I can get existing data/phase diagrams then? Like a book containing a ton of empirical data or something?

Comment: BTW, this separation is rate-dependent. Fresh sea ice contains a lot of salt, for example, and the Czochralski crystallization technique is used to purify semiconductors using a *s l o w l y* traveling region of melting and solidification.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Saturation of multiple solutes](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/29119/saturation-of-multiple-solutes)